# Fetching premake projects inside a project scope based on the given links

Tags: premake

Admitting my current scope is a project

I am using premake-dev

```lua
solution "MySolution"
    project "MyProject"
    ...
    links
    {
      "lib1",
      "lib2",
      ...
    }
```

How could I access the list of projects referenced in the links function.
The purpose is to execute a post-build command that will copy some of the generated libraries to a specific folder.

Should I be storing the project returned value?

```
local proj = project "MyProject"
```

based on that, how would I go about listing the projects listed in links?

**Update**

I sucessfully listed the linked projects using a small piece of code :

```
local prj = project() -- return the current project
local sln = solution() -- returne the current solution
local linkedPrjs = {}
for p in premake.solution.eachproject(sln) do
    if table.find(prj.links, p.name) then
        table.insert(linkedPrjs, p)
    end
end
```

The problem is now different, when premake reaches this piece of code (that is located inside my project, right after the links declaration), configurations are not setup yet.

You cannot use: `premake.project.eachconfig(prj)` as it will throw an error.

So I'm thinking of a registering new action using the API, i'm not sure if this is the best choice:

> premake5 export --target=...

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. your "lib1", etc. are other premake projects ? Or are they external libs ?

Comment: My intent is to locate the built libraries so I can easily manipulate them, copy them to some external folders for non-premake use. Yes all those listed libs are premake projects. I managed to list them all using a small snippet. But this could not do the trick, i'll edit my question and give update

Comment: If those libs are premake projects, wouldn't it be easier to simply copy them from there ? e.g. in your "lib1" project, add a post-build command that copy the lib wherever it needs to be copied ?

Comment: That is what I want to do. But I want an automatic process, not manually set, for it is error prone: each time I will add a library, I will have to ensure it gets copied as well. The purpose is to ease the process of adding new libraries with minimal efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most comprehensive way to handle this would be to override `premake.oven.finishConfig()` and add your custom logic there. That would allow you to leverage all of Premake's existing filtering logic.

```
premake.override(premake.oven.finishConfig, function (base, cfg)
   base(cfg)
   for i = 1, #cfg.links do
      -- add to cfg.postbuildcommands here
   end
end)
```

Depending on your needs, it might be simpler to create your own replacement for `links()`.

```
function my_links(x)
   local prj = project()
   prj.my_links = x
   links(x)
end
```

Then you can fetch `my_links` at any time and operate on it.